# No any plugin found marketplace in Android Studio 3.5

Tags: android-studio-3.5

When I tried to search for a plugin in Android Studio 3.5, it loads then gives 'No results' no matter what plugin I search for. It doesn't show anything in the marketplace.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### I have found a solution.

1. Goto settings > Plugins > settings > manage plugin repositories
2. Just add this https://plugins.jetbrains.com/?_ga=2.162362297.403428945.1567749495-1505371408.1558674007
3. This is the url for jetbrains plugins
4. Now try to search plugin in marketplace

Comment: The url you provided looks a bit strange. Just found a better one https://plugins.jetbrains.com/androidstudio

Comment: No plugins were showing up when I went to Configure -> Plugins. I went to Configure -> Settings -> Plugins, all the plugins were there, I didn't need to add the repo.

Comment: @Tima: This did it